# Possible to remap CapsLock to emulate the "French - Numerical" behavior on a U.S qwerty keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, mapping

I would like to remap the capslock key to behave as such:

- When **Off** :

  - letters are lowercase
  - numbers are not active (symbols characters are active)
  - other symbols (not on the numbers row) behave normally (as if shift was up)
- When **ON**:

  - letters are uppercase
  - numbers are active
  - other symbols (not on the numbers row) are inverted (as if shift was down)

It is the behavior from the "French - Numerical" layout, but I need this on a U.S. keyboard.

Comment: I think you would need to use Ukelele or Karabiner to create a custom keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, as far as I'm aware.

Though I don't think it'd be easy, I guess you could use an app such as [Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele). *I suggest the stable 2.2.8 version, since the 3.0 beta might crash when changing modifier keys.*

1. [Download Ukulele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/render_download.php?format=file&media_id=Ukelele_2.2.8&filename=Ukelele_2.2.8.dmg)
2. Change your keyboard layout to *French - Numerical* ( > **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Input Sources**)
3. In Ukulele: **File** > **New From Current Input Source** (Which is why you changed to French - Numerical in the previous step). After this you can change back to the regular keyboard layout.
4. Essentially change all of the keys to match the English QWERTY.
5. Save your new layout in your **Library** folder > **Keyboard Layouts** (Accessable by pressing ⇧+⌘+G and typing in "~/Library/Keyboard Layouts" and clicking *Go*)
6. Log out and log in again an switch to your new fancy keyboard layout

I think this is the way to go simply because Apple probably did some fancy trickery to make this work for the French layout, so if you base it off of that, you might be able to "trick" the system into accepting the new one.

**Note:** Since we're not *entirely* sure this'll work, I'd recommend only changing a couple of keys to be begin with, as a "proof of concept" (Then, obviously, if it works, simply finish the layout and repeat step 5 and 6).

Good luck!